# Someone going on a question-downvoting spree?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

Fourteen out of fifteen consecutively-asked questions below have been down-voted. Maybe it is like rolling a Yahtzee (possible but improbable), or maybe something else is going on. Anyway, I just found this whole string of down-voted questions odd. (Some of them have gotten up-votes since I asked the question, but I hope you trust me.)

1. [Opengraph meta tag og:type set to "product" errors (like button & URL linter/debug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479503/opengraph-meta-tag-ogtype-set-to-product-errors-like-button-url-linter-deb)
2. [Linux C++ binary namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479505/linux-c-binary-namespace)
3. [ListBox shrinks in size when items added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479506/excel-2007-listbox-shrink-in-size-when-items-added)
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479511/how-do-i-properly-use-this-method
5. [Highlight Current Page in Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479513/highlight-current-page-in-navigation-bar-how-to)
6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479515/gesture-listener-not-working-on-android-phone
7. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479519/cant-install-eclipse-plugins-after-deletion
8. [Reddits voting algorithm, javascript version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479520/reddits-voting-algorithm-javascript-version)
9. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479521/silverlight-common-shared-sessions-different-sites
10. [@font-face rendering issue in Chrome for PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479523/font-face-rendering-issue-in-chrome-for-pc)
11. [Heap Memory Management .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479529/heap-memory-management-net)
12. [Java Split Date Value returned from DB to into separte date and time String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479532/java-split-date-value-returned-from-db-to-into-separte-date-and-time-string)
13. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479533/linq-to-sql-rounding-division
14. [Using CWinFormControl from an ActiveX Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479538/using-cwinformcontrol-from-an-activex-control)
15. [how to write this mysql join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479539/how-to-write-this-mysql-join)

Comment: "Between" how? Questions are sorted in many different ways.

Comment: Sorted by time asked (newest)

Comment: Fourteen out of fifteen questions? I'm sorry I'm way confused here... What fifteen questions?

Comment: @animuson: I viewed the questions sorted by newest.  The two questions I listed were the beginning and end of the range of questions that had the downvotes.  There were thirteen questions between those two.

Comment: News flash: Bad questions get downvoted.  This is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. (The two questions you linked are not good.)

Comment: @Bob: I understand that. But 14 out of 15 questions asked within a span of 5 minutes by different users are bad?  That was my question.  It seemed odd to have that many independent bad questions in a row.

Comment: I appreciate the edits.  Thanks for making my question clearer.

Comment: Ok, a *couple* of those might not have quite deserved downvotes, but those aren't stellar questions.  (Although the one on Heap Memory Management seems good).  Anyway, I seriously think that the community sees most of those as bad questions, I say that based off the fact that several have accumulated multiple downvotes and that one has even been deleted.  SO gets thousands of questions a day; that 15 consecutive ones would be downvote-worthy is not implausible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. "Has anyone else run into this issue?"  A fishing expedition.
2. Seems OK, but a bit obtuse.
3. "Anyone has experience with this issue?" Kinda forum-like.
4. Automatic downvote due to closure.
5. A bit sloppy.
6. "Doesn't Work."
7. Not a Real Question (user abandoned)
8. "Can you fix my code for me?"
9. "Remote Server error: NotFound. Any ideas?"  No other information.
10. "The font shows, but poorly."  What does "poorly" mean?
11. Improved by editing.
12. Didn't ask a question, or state what his problem was.
13. User abandoned this question.
14. "Any pointers?"
15. I honestly don't know what happened to this one.  The community probably thought that the question was too simple.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just a string of sub-par questions.